# Optimal way for withdrawing vested company match from my 401k?

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k

It's possible that I'll be laid off in a few months.

Currently I have `x + y` in my 401k.

```
x = my personal contribution
y = my company match --> which is vested
```

Soon I'll make a fairly big personal, but important purchase. When I leave my job, I plan to withdraw my company's match. Plus I'm young, and have future earnings potential.

My logic is that I'd like to have the spare cash, plus I'll have my degree from an Ivy league school with solid work experience in software engineering.

Is there an ideal way to withdraw the company match 401k, or must I simply accept the 30% hit?

Comment: Do you have any alternative from which you can withdraw without penalty? e.g. a Roth IRA?

Comment: I do have a Roth IRA. Is it preferable to withdraw fro my Roth IRA, and then roll over all of my 401k? If so, why?

Comment: Well, the principal of regular contributions (not conversions or earnings) to a Roth IRA can be withdrawn at any time without tax or penalty, so it can serve as an emergency fund. The main advantage would be no penalty. What you do with your 401k (whether you leave it as is, roll it over to a Traditional IRA, Roth IRA, or new 401k) is an unrelated issue. Another option is to take the best of both approaches -- take a loan from your 401k, but if and when you leave your company and you haven't paid it all back, withdraw from the Roth IRA to pay back the loan to avoid the penalty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want to withdraw only the company match, and presumably leave your personal contributions sitting in your ex-company's 401k plan? **Generally,** 401k plans have larger annual expenses and provide for poorer investment choices than are available to you if you
*roll over* your 401k investments into an IRA. So, unless you have *specific* reasons
for wanting to continue to leave your money in the 401k plan (e.g. you have access to
investments that are *not* available to nonparticipants and you think those investments
are where you want your money to be), roll over part (or all) of your 401k assets into
an IRA, and withdraw the rest for personal expenses.  If your personal contributions
are in a Roth 401k, roll them over to a Roth IRA, but, as I remember it,
company contributions are not part of the Roth 401k and must be rolled over into
a Traditional IRA. Perhaps this is why you want to take those in cash to pay for
your personal purchase?

Also, what is this 30% hit you are talking about? You will owe income tax on
the money withdrawn from the 401k (and custodians traditionally withhold 20%
and send it to the IRS on your behalf) plus penalty for early withdrawal
(which the custodian may also withhold if you ask them), but the tax
that you will pay on the money withdrawn will depend on your tax bracket,
which may be lower if you are laid off and do not immediately take on a
new job. That is, the 30% hit may be on the cash flow, but you may get
some of it back as a refund when you file your income tax return.

Comment: +1 - very comprehensive answer, a hat tip to you. The mental accounting is interesting, the matched funds are equally green, equally valuable. With good earnings ahead, I'd simply avoid the withdrawal, and only transfer to IRA as you suggest.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. So you're saying: roll over x to my Roth IRA, and then withdraw Y for my personal expense. @Joe I need the extra personal cash, otherwise I'd roll over all of my 401k. Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin Your _company match_ will have to be rolled over into a Traditional IRA, not a Roth IRA, though you could, of course, promptly roll over the Traditional IRA into a Roth IRA (paying taxes on the amount rolled over). But you need the cash.... so first decide _how much_ you _must_ have to withdraw, then decide how to divvy up the amount between Roth 401k and company match Traditional 401k, or Roth IRA and Traditional IRA after being let go and doing the roll overs.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - thanks for that explanation. Does it matter whether I do the withdrawal from my Roth IRA or from my 401k?

Answer (score -3):

You can borrow against a 401k for 5 years. This defers any penalty fees that the IRS mandates. Put the cash back in your 401k within those 5 years.

you can also solo administer 401k plans even if you have an unincorporated business, so you can start one of those if you have any other form of cashflow, and there may be a way to get the other plan rolled into your solo one.

http://www.irs.gov/publications/p560/ch04.html#en_US_publink10009053

Comment: When they are laid off the loan become due immediately or it will be counted as income.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep what about if he gets another job (with or without 401k) before he gets laid off. Or what if he claims he is self employed, even unincorporated sole proprietorship is eligible to self administer a 401k solo

Comment: @CQM Your response to mhoran_psprep makes your bad answer worse.

Comment: @DilipSarwate well here is a source from the IRS to back that statement up http://www.irs.gov/publications/p560/ch04.html#en_US_publink10009053 , it specifically mentions unincorporated businesses are also eligible, it actually really lowers the bar for compliance.

Comment: Imagine 100K in companyA 401K, you borrow 50K (the maximum amount), a few months later you are let go. ComapnyA wants the balanced owed (lets say 48K) paid within 30 days. Otherwise they will claim you have a balance of 52K in your account, with a recent withdraw of 48K. The 48K will be taxed and penalized. The actual amounts of the tax and penalty will depend on rates and the state involved.

Comment: -1 More obfuscation of the main point that the 401k loan _must_ be repaid to the **original** 401k plan upon termination of employment, and any rollovers into the 401k plan of a new employer, or a (possibly) bogus solo-401k and re-issuance of a loan from the new 401k is some months later.

Comment: To mhoran's point, even if he had no down time in between jobs, the old job would withhold 20% in his $48k example, there's no provision to directly transfer the loan. If he happens to have $48k handy, even in a short term loan, he can pay it off, transfer the 401(k) and borrow a new loan. But a loan was never part of the question, and isn't a particularly good answer. Sorry.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer its hit or miss, I wasn't familiar with those nuances regarding termination with an employer. Only the nuances regarding opening 401k

Comment: @CQM - now I'm off on this tangent myself - I've not been burned by this myself, but I believe the issue of loans not being transferable is an issue for congress to fix. What a shame that a borrower has this issue when moving jobs, running the risk of the loan being deemed a distribution. I've slowly changed my own view to being very anti-loan. I used to view it as cheap money borrowed from ones self.